# Quickest and most efficient setup for running Matlab applications

Tags: matlab, azure, paas

I've been playing around with things like stacked autoencoders in Matlab for a signal processing application I'm working on. I'm interested in reducing training times by running this application in Azure, but am struggling to figure out what the best setup for doing this would be. After doing a little digging, I found something about a Matlab compute cluster setup, but wasn't sure if this is what I'm looking for. Ideally, whatever setup works best would be (very close to) a plug and play type of scenario without too much setup required to get up and running.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can offer me some advice.

Comment: Can you split the training procedure into a series of tasks that are independent of each other?

Comment: So you are asking how to use the MATLAB Distributed Computing Server? Did you already manage to run it in parallel using local workers, which means your code is basically prepared to run in parallel?